# Titanium listView marker has no listItemIndex property?

Tags: listview, titanium, appcelerator-titanium

When setting a marker on an Alloy `listView` the returned object `onMarker` method does not have the `listItemIndex` and `listSectionIndex` in it.

Does anyone know why this might be?

The `listView` is created using the [`ti.collectionView`](https://github.com/nuno/TiCollectionView) version 3.0.1 from Marcel Pociot

I add the marker like so:

```
$.listView.setMarker({
    sectionIndex: 0,
    itemIndex: (newProducts.length - 1)
})
```

and with

```
function markerReached (e) {
    console.log("reached marker", e)
    $.deliveryCodesWrapper.opacity = 1
}
```

I get

```
reached marker {
    bubbles = 0;
    cancelBubble = 0;
    source = "[object listView]";
    type = marker;
}
```

Where is the `section` and `item index` ?

Answer (score 1):

Probably is something with module.
Because i tested it on my code with a `ListView` and i can get `sectionIndex` and `itemIndex` easily.

My example log:

`onMarker e: {"itemIndex":14,"sectionIndex":0,"bubbles":false,"type":"marker","source":{"canScroll":true,"caseInsensitiveSearch":true,"horizontalWrap":true,"visible":true,"touchEnabled":true,"dictTemplates":{"defaultItem":{}},"defaultItemTemplate":"defaultItem","backgroundColor":"transparent","height":"FILL","layout":"vertical","id":"list","width":"FILL","showVerticalScrollIndicator":true,"top":0},"cancelBubble":false}`

But why you need `sectionIndex` and `itemIndex` on onMarker event? If you simply can get it with `(newProducts.length - 1)` and `sectionIndex` is always 0 (on your code).